Google Script to Open Links
I am trying to use the Google script to open links but hyperlink target text is not visible
I have tried to use the  below code which is not showing the hyperlink text
function testNew(){
  showAnchor('Google','http://Www.google.com');
}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="Google" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"Google")
}


Sir Hyperlink text is not visible on the box after running a code. It's showing only a white box with a Title. Please help here.

If you want to see a link instead of a name in a hyperlink, you need to replace it in the html variable.
Try this code:
function testNew() {
  showAnchor('https://www.google.com');
}

function showAnchor(url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'
    + url + '" target="Google" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'
    + url + '</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  Logger.log(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, "Google")
}



Thank you for your response. However, in the above code, only a blank box is displayed, and no target text is showing would you please look into it again?

There is a second delay, but eventually the link appears. I've added a screencast to the post. Check that the code was copied correctly.

I'm glad. If my answer answers your question you can accept it.
